# Jquery script works in JSfiddle but not on html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/defjam64/w4sGZ/4/) which works as intended.

```
//Jquery script
function icon_hover()
{
    $("#gcp-icon").hover( function(){
       $("#gcp-icon-hover").slideDown();
 },
 function(){
    $("#gcp-icon-hover").slideUp();
});
}

icon_hover();


   //CSS
.site_logo{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.site_logo_hover{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color:#000000;
    opacity:0.6;
    display:none;
}


#gcp-icon
{
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/soDjoS4.png) no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.hover_title{
    color: white;
    width: 220px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 80px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: verdana;
}

.hover_text{
    color: white;
    width: 245px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 25px; 
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size:9pt;
}

.click_me{
    color: white;
    width: 160px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 8px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: verdana;
}

<!--HTML-->
<div class="site_logo" id="gcp-icon">
<div class="site_logo_hover" id="gcp-icon-hover">
    <div class="hover_title" id="gcp-title">Grace Cook Photography</div>
    <div class="hover_text" id="gcp-text">Simple, subtle, clean and good looking</div>
    <div class="click_me">Click for more details</div>
</div>
</div>
```

However, as the title suggests, when this is copied and pasted into a html page and opened in a web browser [see this](http://aljidy.co.uk/jstest.html), this doesn't work as intended.

I have tried debugging. The Javascript is valid and all dependencies(eg. Jquey.js etc.) are available.

Comment: where is the script placed in the page... in header or at the bottom of the page

Comment: It's placed in the header, before the body tag as you can see in the source for http://aljidy.co.uk/jstest.html.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the source from the jsfiddle.net/draft into a html page and it still doesn't work.

Comment: see my answer below... the call to `icon_hover` should be in a dom ready handler

Comment: I accepted @ArunPJohny 's answer due to being the most comprehensive and quickest to implement. It may not be the best practice or work in all cases but I can't really check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be, in jsfiddle the script was executed on dom ready ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JuYSD/1/) not working outside the dom ready handler).... but in your page it doesn't look like that

In jsfiddle the second dropdown in the LHS panel selects the place where the script will be added, by default it is added as a `window.onload` handler.

So move the invocation of `icon_hover` to a dom ready handler

```
jQuery(function(){
    icon_hover();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JuYSD/)

Answer (score 2):

you should use always ready event when  you are working on webpage...

```
$(function(){
icon_hover();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your startup method bindings inside.document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){//your code here.});
```

Also check for any duplicate html elements having same Id.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $("#gcp-icon").hover(
        function () {
            $( "#gcp-icon-hover" ).slideDown();
        },
        function () {
            $( "#gcp-icon-hover" ).slideUp();
        }
    )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check carefully on jsfiddle... When you select your JS library (jQuery 1.10.1 in your case) underneath this option jsFiddle automatically selects for you onLoad.
What this does is it puts all your javascript code within a

```
$(window).load(function()
{ 
    //yourcode from jsfiddle goes in here
}
```

This will load your js code when the windows loads.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){icon_hover();});
```